# look down at vs. look down on

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference, phrasal-verbs

Are ***look down on*** and ***look down at*** synonymous? They are when referring to dictionaries, but I'd like to know the subtle difference between them.

> The ancient Greeks used to describe two very different ways of
> thinking — *logos* and *mythos*. *Logos* roughly referred to the world
> of the logical, the empirical, the scientific. *Mythos* referred to
> the world of dreams, storytelling and symbols. Like many rationalists
> today, some philosophers of Greece prized *logos* and ***looked down
> at*** *mythos*. Logic and reason, they concluded, make us modern;
> storytelling and mythmaking are primitive. But lots of scholars then
> and now — including many anthropologists, sociologists and
> philosophers today — see a more complicated picture, where *mythos*
> and *logos* are intertwined and interdependent. Science itself,
> according to this view, relies on stories. The frames and metaphors we
> use to understand the world shape the scientific discoveries we make;
> they even shape what we see. When our frames and metaphors change, the
> world itself is transformed. The Copernican Revolution involved more
> than just scientific calculation; it involved a new story about the
> place of Earth in the universe.

[Useful Delusions: The Power and Paradox of the Self-Deceiving Brain](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=66G6DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT57&lpg=PT57&dq=Mythos%20referred%20to%20the%20world%20of%20dreams,%20storytelling%20and%20symbols.%20Like%20many%20rationalists%20today,%20some%20philosophers%20of%20Greece%20prized%20logos%20and%20looked%20down%20at%20mythos.%20Logic%20and%20reason,%20they%20concluded,%20make%20us%20modern;%20storytelling%20and%20mythmaking%20are%20primitive.&source=bl&ots=IHCzwJQJIq&sig=ACfU3U2TPC7cppcyzG301Ap2q-h2KEvWiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwhunMl_b8AhXos1YBHWN0AVwQ6AF6BAghEAM#v=onepage&q=Mythos%20referred%20to%20the%20world%20of%20dreams%2C%20storytelling%20and%20symbols.%20Like%20many%20rationalists%20today%2C%20some%20philosophers%20of%20Greece%20prized%20logos%20and%20looked%20down%20at%20mythos.%20Logic%20and%20reason%2C%20they%20concluded%2C%20make%20us%20modern%3B%20storytelling%20and%20mythmaking%20are%20primitive.&f=false)

Comment: How thoroughly did you consult dictionaries? The figurative meaning of 'look down on' is to be found very widely.

Answer (score 5):

As with so many questions like these, the answer is "it depends." If you are standing on a hill, you can *look down on* or *look down at* a village in the valley. [This ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+down+on+the+scene%2Clook+down+at+the+scene&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that both *look down at the scene* and *look down on the scene* are used, although *look down on* is more common.

But in a figurative rather than a literal sense, if you *look down on someone*, you are thinking less of that person than of yourself. To use *look down at someone* to mean this is very rare at best; if you *look down at* someone, you're generally doing it in the literal sense of, say, looking down the stairs at someone standing in the hall.

The example you give is the only time I've ever seen *at* used in this way. An ngram viewer of *look down at/on the idea* has no examples using *at*, and quite a few examples using *on*. This gives me the idea that as an editor, I would correct the passage from *at* to *on*.

Now, there's an idiomatic expression *look down one's nose at* something, which has a similar meaning to *look down on*. Maybe that's where this comes from.

Doing some more research, I see your excerpt comes from a book authored by one Shankar Vedantam. Perhaps this is a peculiarity of Indian English speakers, but it is not otherwise standard.

Answer (score 5):

To 'look down **at**' can mean, literally, to observe or see from a higher place, e.g. from the top floor of my house, I can look down **at** the tops of cars in the street below. It doesn't really have a figurative meaning.

To 'look down **on**' can mean, literally, the same thing, but it also has a figurative meaning: 'despise' or 'regard with a feeling of superiority'.

It is clear from the context you gave that the authors intended the second, figurative meaning (some philosophers of Greece prized *logos* and regarded *mythos* with a feeling of superiority).

There are certain signs in the text that it was possibly poorly edited prior to publication, and maybe prepared by non-native or unskilled English speakers. I find 'philosophers of Greece' awkward when 'Greek philosophers' is so obviously more appropriate.

Comment: The book is actually pretty interesting. You should take a look at it.